# Why do some types in Flow libdefs have dollar sign in the begining

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

Some libdefs in `flow-typed` respository have types, started with the dollar sign, like `$AxiosXHR`:

[image]

It looks like it declares globally available type, but I am not sure, and I haven't found any documentation about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now there's not a good way to write types inside `declare module {}` bodies that *aren't* exported, so the best option is to put a declaration outside the `declare module {}` and reference it.
To prevent clashing names, it's a convention to put something like `$npm$ModuleName$` before the type/var name.

Ref: [`flow-typed` CONTRIBUTING notes](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#prefix-global-variables-that-arent-really-meant-to-be-global)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be true. And this is strange, because documentation explicitly says, that types, which are not referenced in `module.exports`, will not be exported: https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/#toc-declaring-a-commonjs-module. But I tried to declare my own libdef, and all the typed inside of module scope are available.